# Nav bar sub menu displaying behind images

Tags: html, css, slider

i have a CSS menu with this CSS Code:

```
#cssmenu ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; text-align: center; }
#cssmenu li { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu a { margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {list-style: none;}
#cssmenu a {text-decoration: none;}
#cssmenu {height: 50px; background-color: #f36f25; box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15px;
    position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 16px 20px;
-webkit-transition: color .15s;
   -moz-transition: color .15s;
     -o-transition: color .15s;
        transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {color: #ffffff; background-color:#666666; }
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -90px;
    width: 180px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
     -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
        transition: all .3s .1s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 50px;
    visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    border-color: transparent transparent rgb(250,250,250) transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li { position: relative;}
#cssmenu ul ul a{
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
    display: block;
-webkit-transition: background-color .1s;
   -moz-transition: background-color .1s;
     -o-transition: background-color .1s;
        transition: background-color .1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {background-color: #f36f25;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -16px;
    left: 206px;
    padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
-webkit-transition: all .3s;
   -moz-transition: all .3s;
     -o-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; left: 196px; visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover{
    background-color: #f36f25;
    color: rgb(240,240,240);
}
```

There is a slider underneath the nav code but the sub menus on the navigation are displaying behind the images on the slider, any ideas what i can do to get them to display in front of the slider images?

JS Fiddle of the menu is here: http://jsfiddle.net/JLRte/

Comment: can you include a fiddle that replicates your entire problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `z-index` to the menu: `#cssmenu *{ z-index: 999 }` Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JLRte/1/

Comment: perfect thank you - do you know how i can make the hover background on the orange bar stay with a background colour when you hover over links on the sub menu?

Comment: No problem: http://jsfiddle.net/JLRte/3/ I changed the selector on line 25. Please mark my post as 'best answer' for future users.